# Can we make 30,000 Office 365 API calls daily?

Tags: office365

We currently offer a calendar application that makes 30,000 calls to Google calendar daily and we are now building the Office 365 version using the REST APIs. However, we have a few questions.

1. Should we be aware of any rate limiting per user, application, or IP address? We ask because expect to make about 30,000 API calls once we roll this out to our user base and we want to be sure this won't pose any issues. If so, is there a process for increasing this limit or getting added to a whitelist?
2. Can we consistently expect response times under 2 seconds? In our preliminary testing, we've found response times as fast as 2 seconds and as slow as 20 seconds. Is there any logic to prioritize / de-prioritize calls that we should know about?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about vendor license use/restrictions and not about programming as defined in  the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Just to give you some support. Have you tried talking to Microsoft about this? Your 2nd question can be answered by further testing. You seem to know what the answer is already.

Comment: Ken - I wish it were a licensing question as we'd be very happy to pay for assurance that we won't run into any throttling issues. The REST API is new and we can't find any documentation on quotas, limits or performance benchmarks.  What we want to know is if we'll run into any technical issues with that type of usage volume.

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to say “sure, 30,000 requests is no problem” given that there are a lot of factors that could change the answer.  Not all requests place equal load on the system, and the system may be under higher load when you make the request, which may result in different throttling behavior that at other times of the day. It’s best to code your app to anticipate the possibility of being throttled and handle it accordingly.

That being said, currently the service doesn’t provide a lot of information when you get throttled. You may get a 500 or 503 HTTP response, with “The server cannot service this request right now. Try again later.” in the response payload. If you get a 500, you should fail the call. If you get a 503, you should implement a backoff scheme to re-issue the requests. We’re working on improving the throttling responses to provide more information to your app to allow it to respond in an appropriate manner.